# How to configure a site to automatically link domains

Tags: google-analytics

Source:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/cross-domain#configuring_a_site_to_accept_linker_parameters

Reference:

If the destination domain has been configured to automatically link domains, it will accept linker parameters by default.

---

I assume there is an HTML based solution for me to implement configuring a destination domain to automatically link domains.

How can I do this?

Comment: And for the love of god, can people that write documentation learn to use active voice? And hyperlinks?

Comment: What i think actually happens is that on the source you have `destination.com` and in destination you have `accept_incoming : true`  that's the "automatic" linking they are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

We have been using this approach. I'm not sure if it is correct, but it is *an* answer.

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXX"></script>
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'UA-66686611-1', {
  'linker': {
    'domains': ['every.com','domain.com','that.com','I.com','will.com','link.com','to.com','or.com','from.com'],
    'accept_incoming': true,
    'decorate_forms': true
  },

});
</script>
```